# Any way to access resource from ADAL.NET Library (native apps) on a web browser without having to do login activity again?

Tags: office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently creating Universal Windows App (native) that uses Microsoft Graph API. For authentication, I used ADAL for .NET library by calling GetTokenAsync() on the AuthenticationContext (https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet). The library will automatically prompt a login window for the user to enter its credentials.

Later I was required to open a OneNote URL on a web browser. I managed to get the note URL from the Microsoft Graph API (OneNote API) and then I realized when I tried to open the URL on a browser I was redirected to the Microsoft login page (http://login.microsoftonline.com).

This is not very good for user experience because they needed to enter their credentials twice (on the ADAL prompt window and on the browser). Is there any way whatsoever so that the user can do the login activity only once?

Answer (score 0):

User needs to enter their creds on Microsoft online website but not twice. please debug the app and store this context ticket so you can use it in your win universial app. by the way, make sure that you are not pointing your app to two different api endpoints. go with the Microsoft graph api endpoint but not any other legacy endpoint for your app. Hope this helps.

Comment: How do I get the context ticket? Yes, I am using latest https://graph.microsoft.com/ as the endpoint.